# Selenium IDE test cases on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, safari, internet-explorer-9

I used Selenium IDE for testing on Firefox but now I want to use the same test cases on other browsers like Chrome, IE9 and Safari. What can I do to do this?

Comment: I would highly recommend a book call Selenium Simplified. Just started a QA tester internship and it's taught me SO much useful stuff. With a little bit of tweaking, I've managed to get it so that I can run testing scripts on every browser with the exception of Safari. All the software used in the book is free =] http://www.amazon.co.uk/Selenium-Simplified-Selenium-RC-Java-JUnit/dp/0956733239/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1386611038&sr=1-1&keywords=selenium+simplified Hope this helps!

Comment: The IDE specifically is an extension for Firefox. The best you can do is use the WebDriver-backed playback: http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/02/18/webdriver-playback-in-selenium-ide-is-here/ ...however this is just a band-aid solution. The IDE is not a tool designed for complex multi-browser testing. You may be able to tape over this using the link I've shown, but it is *not* a reasonable solution to the problem. Taking the power of WebDriver and an actual programming language is the *real* solution.

Answer (score 2):

To run selenium IDE generated script into another browser, you need to store all your test script under test suite.
Then you can run that test suite with selenium RC server.

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "insert_browser_name_here"
"insert_root_domain_here" "insert_full_path_to_suite_here"
"insert_a_full_path_to_store_reports_here"
```

In above command you need to pass suite location, browser name, base URL, and location for result.

For selenium support browser you can refer 
http://radical-qa.blogspot.in/2012/03/selenium-supported-browsers.html

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is the Firefox extension. To run your tests on other browsers, you'll need another tool, [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), for example.

PS I think that Webdriver actually is the next evolution step for QA automation, IDE lacks flexibility a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found the same solution as above but explained in mere detail here: http://www.qafriend.com/selenium/running-selenium-script-on-internet-explorer-and-chrome